# web.xml property override by Weblogic deployment plan

Tags: deployment, weblogic, weblogic11g

Trying to override my web.xml file's

```
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

I tried using the following deployment plan which seems like it should work ... but it does not seem to.  I need to either remove the login-config or change it to client-cert.

```
  <variable-definition>    
     <variable>   
        <name>authMethod</name>  
        <value>CLIENT-CERT</value>  
      </variable>
   </variable-definition>
......
   <module-descriptor external="false">
      <root-element>web-app</root-element>
      <uri>WEB-INF/web.xml</uri>
      <variable-assignment>
        <name>authMethod</name>
        <xpath>/web-app/login-config/auth-method</xpath>
        <operation>replace</operation>
      </variable-assignment>
    </module-descriptor>
```

Comment: This does look correct to me. Have you verified it is actually using your deployment plan? You can check using WLS console.

Comment: Console does not show much. However there is another variable that is being injected correctly, so I assume it is working ... to an extent.

Comment: @DmitryB were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: not really clear. During one of the tests on a test app it seemed to have worked after restarting the server instance. So try that.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and found that by default Weblogic's Plan Generator generates plan.xml with the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<deployment-plan xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/deployment-plan" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/deployment-plan    
    http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/deployment-plan/1.0/deployment-plan.xsd" 
    global-variables="false">
```

Changing the `global-variables="false"` to `global-variables="true"` fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

try modifying your xpath to the following:

```
 <xpath>/web-app/login-config/auth-method/[param-name="authMethod"]/param-value</xpath>
```